# How to fit screenshot images into iPhone frame display

Tags: html

I have changed the screenshot/images displayed inside the iPhone frame on my website, but the new images are hanging over the sides of the frame.

The new screenshot images are not the same ratio as the old ones, so I guess this is probably the issue?

Old Images: **325x666**

New Images: **750x1334 (325x578)**

```
<div class="col-md-6 pull-md-6">
  <div class="lt-video">
  <div class="lt-mobile">  
  <div class="wrapper-video">            
  <div class="main-slider">
  <div class="slider-item">
  <img src="assets/img/slider/11.png" alt="">               
</div>
```

I want the images to fit neatly inside the iPhone frame, without losing the existing ratio

Answer (score 0):

Set size for images through HTML or CSS.

Have you tried:

```
<img class="resize" src="assets/img/slider/11.png" width="200" height="40" alt="">
```

OR

```
img.resize {
    max-width:50vw;
    max-height:50vh;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Comet. Neither of those appear to fix the problem though.